# C Macros for 2 and 3 dimensional indexing

Tags: c, macros

I'm looking for a shortcut for 2 and 3 dimensional indexing of arbitrary values, and I know this works for a given array a[]

```
#define a(i,j,k) a[(i)*span*span+(j)*span+(k)]
#define b(i,j) b[(i)*span+(j)]
```

But I don't understand how to allow these macros to operate on arbitrary arrays eg;

```
x(i,j,k)
```

Anyone care to clue me in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't define the macro name to `a` or `b`, instead, give the array as parameter:

```
#define arr3d(a,i,j,k) a[(i)*span*span+(j)*span+(k)]
#define arr2d(b,i,j) b[(i)*span+(j)]
```

Then `a` and `b` will be parameters and you'll be able to use it for different arrays.

**Edit**

For example:
char newarr[5][5][5];
arr3d(newarr, 3, 3, 3);

also, if `span` is not a variable defined in all scopes where you need to use this macro, it will not work, and you'll need to add another parameter to the macro - span, so the macro definition will look like:

```
#define arr3d(a,i,j,k,span) a[(i)*(span)*(span)+(j)*(span)+(k)]
```

**And yes, I would usually avoid this.**

Answer (score 1):

get your compiler to preprocess the macros without compiling them to debug macros.

`gcc -E -P` for gcc.

Answer (score 0):

This macro will expand anything of the form `a(i,j,k)` into the form `a[(i)*span*span+(j)*span+(k)]`. It doesn't specifically use those values (by expecting them to be variables), however.
Thus, if you use `x(i,j,k)`, it will replace all `a`s in the macro with `x`s.

Comment: So thats a macro for every variable?

Comment: Yeah. The C preprocessor expands your variables as needed. For instance, `#define DOUBLE(x) (2*(x))` will double _any_ variable you give it, not specifically the variable x

Comment: Whoa, sorry, brainsnap. No, the name of the macro won't be substituted in, however the arguments it takes (i, j, k) will be. The array name will need to be a parameter if you want a global macro

Answer (score 0):

As it looks your dimension `span` seems to be a compile time integer constant? Then you just shouldn't use a macro. If you use

```
double A[span][span][span] = { 0 };
```

or similar, where

```
#define span 42
```

or

```
enum { span = 42 };
```

indexing in C with `A[i][j][k]` will work out of the box and do the right thing. Don't complicate your life with an opaque macro for such cases.